# Reinstalling the El Pais scope on Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps, scopes

The other day I was cleaning my Ubuntu phone from apps that had been installed by default and I didn't want. I uninstalled El Pais thinking it was a webapp not related to the scope, which I find way more convenient, but after that the scope disappeared and El Pais is not an available source any more on the news aggregator. I've looked for it on the Ubuntu Store but it's impossible to find it.

Do you know how I can get my El Pais scope back?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal and run this command

```
click info com.canonical.elpais
```

and see what version you have. Then,

```
click register com.canonical.elpais <version>
```

substitue `<version>` with yours.

It should work since you didn't remove it from the preinstalled system (you can find it in /custom/click/com.canonical.scopes.elpais).

Info about the click command: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/click.1.html